# Server Certificate Error on publish, .Net core 5.0, IIS server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, .net-core, certificate

I am trying to publish my .net core 5.0 application to our IIS Server. Every time I do I keep getting the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("myServer") using the specified process ("Web Management Service"), but could not verify the server’s certificate. If you trust the server, connect again and allow untrusted certificates.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED.)

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659696/publishing-from-visual-studio-2015-allow-untrusted-certificates) over the same issue. No matter what configuration I use in my publish profile though it does not seem to work. I am a bit confused that the publish profile I imported does not contain PropertyGroup information or anything like that. Just the publishProfile tag with relevant information.

**PublishSettings:**

Here are my publish settings. What do I need to add in order to get my publishing of the app to ignore the server cert? Again I just want to say I tried adding the **AllowUntrustedCertificate** and multitude of other suggestions from that other post. Is that setting supposed to go inside the publishProfile information or just right after it within the PublishData? Either way nothing I do works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<publishData>
  <publishProfile
    publishUrl="https://MYSERVER:8172/msdeploy.axd"
    msdeploySite="ToolController"
    destinationAppUrl="http://myWebSite"
    mySQLDBConnectionString=""
    SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
    profileName="Default Settings"
    publishMethod="MSDeploy"
    userName="myUserName" />
</publishData>
```

I am also using Visual Studio 2019 in case that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I am not sure why but using the normal method I typically do. By going to the IIS server -> right clicking the site -> Deploy -> Configure Web Deploy Publishing was not working at all.

Instead I opted to use the visual studio option of generating the publish file by doing Web Server (IIS) -> filling in the relevant info. I then added the

```
<AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
```

and everything worked fine.