# Web Deployment through MSDeploy.exe

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy, web-deployment-project

I'm configuring a CI build server with Jenkins. After the build steps I'd like to deploy the website.

When publishing the the website from VisualStudio I published by Web Deploy. I like that method because it actually publish those file which have changed, so the deploy is really quick.

Now on the build server I'm trying to do the same: build the application (using `MSBuild.exe`), and then deploy the application (using `MSDeploy.exe`?).

I've seen some post where they deploy the application using `MSBuild.exe` and others using `MSDeploy.exe`, is there a significant difference in there?

Do you have any advice that could help with this?

Thanks and advanced.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use MSBuild to create an MSDeploy package and then MSDeploy.exe to deploy that package to any environments.  This link should help you gain a better understanding of how WebDeploy/MSDeploy works.

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/

Whats REALLY cool is you can also use MSDeploy to deploy databases and non-web applications too.  We have fully automated the deployment of 50+ products using this method.

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/18/deploy-non-web-apps-with-msdeploy/

**UPDATED** - Basic steps to use MSDeploy packages:

1. Create a package in your build by adding the `/t:Package` arg to your MSBuild call
2. Store the resulting package form the `bin` directory to your artifact repo
3. Call MSDeploy.exe to deploy the package to your target server.  There are lots of options here but
   the basic command follows:

   "c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package=mypackage.zip -dest:auto,computerName=localhost

Comment: Can you please summarize the information from the links so that your answer is complete on its own?

Comment: Added a few more details.

Answer (score 1):

Even easier using current Visual Studio and dotnet, create your Publish Profile in Visual Studio, then use dotnet on the CI server:

```
dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile=PROFILE-NAME /p:Password=*****
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles.md

Comment: Providing the password in this way, in combination with adding an `AllowUntrustedCertificate` tag to our .pubxml (as in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44288258)) is what worked for us, since our certificate was failing the revocation check.